# Do not show comments on Buddypress activity page.

Tags: android-activity, comments, buddypress

I would like the comments on my Buddypress Activity page to be like Facebooks. At the moment, the default shows comments. 
I would like it, if the comments did not show on the activity page  but shows when the reader clicks through to read the full post.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bp-default then you can edit `bp-default/activity/entry.php` to display the comments only on the full activity item page - I do believe this page is referred to as the activity 'permalink' or the 'single activity' page.

Wrap the comment output in a conditional check like this:

```
if ( bp_is_single_activity() ) {
    // comment output
}
```